# how to change terminal command's heading to a default

Tags: terminal

the terminal heading I have now is very long, which is `myname@my-computer:~/directory`

I know I can type `PS1='$'` for each new terminal, so the heading is `$`, but how can I set it to be default?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this in your `~/.bashrc` file ;)

Then, `source` it :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```